# Check Hidden Form Input has Value on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="productID" id="productID" value="">
```

I have a hidden Alert (using Bootstrap for this):

```html
<div id="alert_ajax_error" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
  You have not made a selection. Please select an Item and try again
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

The hidden form input is populated via another script when users select from a table - it adds the productID as the value of the input.

I would now like to add some client side validation (have server side validation in place) so that if the user clicks Submit it checks to see if they have made a selection by checking for the presence of the hidden input to see if it has a value - if it is empty it will then show the hidden alert:

```
$("#alert_ajax_error").show();
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to check a hidden input with Javascript/JQuery and how to go about this if it is possible.

Comment: Does your form currently have any front end error handling on submit or input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will want to check the value on submit using an if statement

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     if($('#productID').val() == '') {

          $("#alert_ajax_error").show();

          return false;

     }

     //.... more form actions if good ....

});
```

Comment: just noticed that the form is not submitting if it passes the test. It does show the alert if there is no hidden input value but if there is it's not submitting the form - any idea what's missing here?

Comment: event.preventDefault() is stopping the default action

Comment: what does your form handler look like?